# How do I get number of fields in JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JavaScript object as an associative array and everything was well until I needed to get number of entries that are stored in it. What is the easiest and most elegant way to do that? All I can think of is to run `for each` loop or jQuery `$.each` function and just see how much iterations it would do but that looks like an an awful thing to do.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Old Firefox supports the `__count__` property. Newer environments support ES5's `Object.keys`. For older environments we have to fallback to just iterating over the object and counting manually (ugh!):

```
function count(obj) {

    if (obj.__count__ !== undefined) { // Old FF
        return obj.__count__;
    }

    if (Object.keys) { // ES5 
        return Object.keys(obj).length;
    }

    // Everything else:

    var c = 0, p;
    for (p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            c += 1;
        }
    }

    return c;

}
```

Comment: Oh my god, O(n) to get the number of entries in a map... Well, this sucks. :/

Comment: (Not saying your answer is not correct btw. Just disappointed by JS...)

Comment: What does old browsers mean? See: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys

Answer (score 54):

This worked for me:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Comment: IE specific it looks like (see James' answer.)

Comment: This works in Node.js so it's probably not specific to IE anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this has been answered on here before, and/or googling can lead you in the right direction.  Nevertheless let me point out that one of the biggest gotchas if you use a loop in the form of:

```
for (var attr in obj) { ....
```

Is that the object could be cluttered with properties you did not necessarily add, and the standard solution to this as I recall is to additionally use the test for hasOwnProperty, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to that, or keeping count when you add and delete properties from the object.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately there isn't really a good way to know the number of properties in an object without iterating over them. The following is fairly simple though:

```
function countProps(obj) {
    var l = 0;
    for (p in obj) l++;
    return l;
}

var bob = { a: 1, b: 2};

alert(countProps(bob));
```